# How to retrieve item closest to another item in DynamoDB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamo DB table where the sort key has a numeric value.
I have a requirement to retrieve the first item which has a lower value than the one, that I have.

I have gone through http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#API_UpdateItem_Examples docs but I can see no way to:
- sort the output
- limit the result to 1 entry

Is there any way to actually achieve what I want with dynamo DB?

EDIT:
According to this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html 
The results are sorted using sorting key, and when it's numeric, they are sorted descending. Which is great, but I still can't find any way to get only a single result [don't want to "pay" for the full table scan in some cases].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you searching for the next item which has a lower sort key within the same Partition Key?

In that case, you are able to use Query as you've found, sort in Descending and Limit to 1. This will not scan the entire table.

Alternatively, if you wish you scan cross Partitions, unfortunately a Table Scan is the only way to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Abhaya. I don't know how I have missed the `Limit`!